# :active pseudo-class does not work correctly

Tags: jquery, css, css3pie

I have the below code that modifies `div.ball` when a label is clicked:

```
$("div.btnyesno").find("label.yes").click(function() {
    $(this).parents().eq(1).find("div.ball")
          .removeClass("btnNo")
          .addClass("btnYes");
});
$("div.btnyesno").find("label.no").click(function() {  
    $(this).parents().eq(1).find("div.ball")
          .removeClass("btnYes")
          .addClass("btnYNo");
});
```

it works fine.

Now, this is the **HTML code**:

```
<div class="bandejas">
    <label>Bandejas</label>
    <div class="btnyesno">
        <input type="radio" name="bandejas" id="bdj_1" value="1">
        <input type="radio" name="bandejas" id="bdj_2" value="2">
        <label role="button" for="bdj_1" id="bdj1" class="yes">1</label>
        <div class="containerball">  
            <div class="ball"></div>
        </div>
        <label role="button" for="bdj_2" id="bdj2" class="no">2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

My intent is alter the **js code** to **css**

I try of the above form. I works by half.

```
div.btnyesno > label.yes:active ~ div.containerball > div.ball{
    left: 5px !important;
    background: blue;
}

div.btnyesno > label.no:active ~ div.containerball > div.ball{
    right: 5px !important;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

At click in the label, the ball is foating to lef as expeted, but when i leave the mouse, then the ball back to original position automatly.

What to do to fix it wrong?

```css
div.btnyesno > input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}
div.btnyesno {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
}
div.btnyesno > div.containerball {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 500px;
}
div.btnyesno > div.containerball > div.ball {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    left: 50px;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background: #ccc;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 500px;
    transition: all 500ms;
}
div.btnyesno > label{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.btnyesno > label.yes {
    left: -10px;
}
div.btnyesno > label.no {
    right: -10px;
}   
.btnYes {
    left: 5px !important;
    background: blue !important;
}
.btnNo {
    right: 5px !important;
    background: #ccc !important;
}

div.btnyesno > label.yes:active ~ div.containerball > div.ball{
    left: 5px !important;
    background: blue;
}

div.btnyesno > label.no:active ~ div.containerball > div.ball{
    right: 5px !important;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="bandejas">
    <label>Bandejas</label>
    <div class="btnyesno">
        <input type="radio" name="bandejas" id="bdj_1" value="1">
        <input type="radio" name="bandejas" id="bdj_2" value="2">
        <label role="button" for="bdj_1" id="bdj1" class="yes">1</label>
        <div class="containerball">  
            <div class="ball"></div>
        </div>
        <label role="button" for="bdj_2" id="bdj2" class="no">2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**:

I try this form:

```
div.btnyesno > input:nth-child(1):checked ~ div.containerball > div.ball {
    left: 5px !important;
    background: blue;
}
div.btnyesno > input:nth-child(2):checked ~ div.containerball > div.ball {
    right: 5px !important;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

its works. But, how its is verys blocks:

Once to "bandejas", other for "shipping free", other for 'bloq', then the first block, works fine, but the others is checking automatly and only.

Comment: That’s not what `:active` does. The `:active` pseudoclass applies when mousedown happens, and is removed when mouseup fires, or the cursor is moved off the element. If you want to track state with plain CSS then you’ll need to use something like a checkbox, and the `:checked` pseudoclass.

Comment: i Cannot, 'cause i am using the label in the place of radio button.

Comment: You need somewhere to hold state. Normally in JS that state would be a boolean variable, but if you’re purely relying on CSS then you’ll need some other state holder. Typically you’d pick an element that has a `:checked` state (a checkbox or, at a pinch, a radio button). An alternative approach would be to have a link pointing at an element with an id attribute. This would let you use the `:target` pseudoclass instead, which might be enough for what you want?

Comment: exemple, change of label to button?

Comment: I think that yes. But see pelase in the final of my questin. I put a soluctiom, but with a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".labelClick").on("click", function() {
    if($(this).attr('rel') === 'yes'){
    
      $(this).parents().eq(1).find("div.ball")
      .removeClass("btnNo")
      .addClass("btnYes");
      
    }else if( $(this).attr('rel') ==='no' ){
    
    $(this).parents().eq(1).find("div.ball")
      .removeClass("btnYes")
      .addClass("btnYNo");
    }
        
    });



})
```

Comment: no. friend. I whant exclude nthe js code then use the css code.